# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. Exception occurs when _trd1 starts

Tags: android

Exception occurs when _trd1 starts.
Why it is giving an exception.
I have an imageView on which i have set an Animation.
Same as i did on _imageCard2 they working both fine...
but when i added a new thread it gives an exception after its completion.

```
public void AnimFunction() {

    TranslateAnimation animation2 = new TranslateAnimation(0, -50, 0, 0);
    animation2.setDuration(100); // duration in ms
    animation2.setRepeatCount(1);
    animation2.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    animation2.setFillAfter(false);
    _imageView.startAnimation(animation2);

    _imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.b1fv);

    // Animation

    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 150, 0, 0);
    animation.setDuration(400); // duration in ms
    animation.setRepeatCount(1);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    animation.setFillAfter(false);
    _imageCard2.startAnimation(animation);

    Thread _trd1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(2000);
                _imageCard2.setImageResource(R.drawable.sk);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    _trd1.start();

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
Thread _trd1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                sleep(2000);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    _imageCard2.setImageResource(R.drawable.sk);
                }
            });

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: ImageView.setImageResource may only be called from the UI thread, but you are calling it from _trd1, which is not the UI thread.  Fortunately, Activity exposes runOnUiThread method which convenientlyallows you to execute a runnable on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to modify UI components from a thread different than the UI thread.

Consider using a Handler with your thread.

You can also do your background processing in an AsyncTask which has ways to update the UI.

**Edit:** Some explanation:

UI = User Interface.

Your activity runs in a main thread which is the UI thread.

You're not allowed to modify UI components (Buttons, ImageViews, etc.) except from the UI thread.

When you created your trd1 thread you attempted to modify an ImageView from it. That's why you got the error.

`runOnUiThread()` is one of the methods you can use to make the modifications happen on the UI thread rather than your newly created thread.

Comment: Thank you @Benito for replying to my question but I dont understand what is UI components and UI thread.

Comment: UI = User Interface. Your activity runs in a main thread which is the UI thread. You're not allowed to modify UI components (Buttons, ImageViews, etc.) except from the UI thread. When you created your trd1 thread you attempted to modify an ImageView from it. That's why you got the error. `runOnUiThread()` is one of the methods you can use to make the modifications happen on the UI thread rather than your newly created one.